# URL alias for each country, URL should display Description

Tags: 7, database

```
<?php  
        $dbresult = db_query("SELECT country_name,description FROM {countries} WHERE status='1' order by country_name ASC");
        $theanswer[] = $row->country_name;

        ?>
        <ul>
        <li><a class="normal-list list-group-item active" href="#">Countries</a></li>
        <li><form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
                <fieldset>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filter" value="" placeholder="Search By Country" />
                <span id="filter-count"></span>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </li>
        <li>
            <ul class="commentlist">
            <?php foreach($dbresult as $row){ ?><li></li>
            <li><a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i><?php echo $row->country_name; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
```

$dbresult = db_query("SELECT country_name,description FROM {countries} WHERE status='1' order by country_name ASC");
        $theanswer[] = $row->country_name;

```
    ?>
    <ul>
    <li><a class="normal-list list-group-item active" href="#">Countries</a></li>
    <li><form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
            <fieldset>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="filter" value="" placeholder="Search By Country" />
            <span id="filter-count"></span>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul class="commentlist">
        <?php foreach($dbresult as $row){ ?><li></li>
        <li><a class="list-group-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i><?php echo $row->country_name; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

I am using drupal 7 , I have created custom modules for adding countries and edit/delete/status like this.. enter image description here

The attached image having my database table..

Now i am able to display all countries list ....and filtering live search as well..

Now i want link each country description as one page content...like dynamic pages based on country select link redirect to country description page...[Table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZcRp.png)